# How I can create a wallet from keypair in frontend?

Tags: wallet, keypair

I want to sign some view transactions in frontend using  a random keypair instead of wallet provider like phantom or solflare to avoid **Approve** popup

I tried to create wallet like this:

```
import { Wallet } from '@project-serum/anchor'
import { Keypair } from '@solana/web3.js'

const wallet1 = new Wallet(Keypair.generate())
```

---

But I got this error:

```
TypeError: _project_serum_anchor__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__.Wallet is not a constructor
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import NodeWallet from '@project-serum/anchor/dist/cjs/nodewallet'
let wallet = new NodeWallet(Keypair.generate())
```

Comment: Got this error in NextJS when used tried NodeWallet:

`./node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/dist/cjs/nodewallet.js:17:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'

Import trace for requested module:
./pages/timer.tsx

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
`